# ORACLE Permissions on tables

Tags: oracle

I have a table orders in OE schema. I don't have access to this table either from scott or hr schemas . But when I try to select from oe.orders from these 2 schemas I get different messages as below.Why is this so?

```
SQL> connect scott/test
Connected.
SQL> select count(*) from oe.orders;
select count(*) from oe.orders
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL> connect hr/test
Connected.
SQL> select count(*) from oe.orders;
select count(*) from oe.orders
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: Do you have any table synonyms defined ?

Comment: No Synonyms to the table Orders - I Checked dba_synonyms table

Comment: What is the object type of each?  With views, it might be throwing a different error if you can't access the underlying table.

Comment: it is a table not any other object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCOTT may have INSERT, UPDATE, and/or DELETE privileges on the table oe.orders, but not SELECT, while HR clearly has no privileges granted at all on oe.orders. SCOTT could also have INSERT ANY TABLE, DELETE ANY TABLE, and/or UPDATE ANY TABLE as well.

Be sure to look in dba_sys_privs for granted system privileges that might confer the ability to know an object such as a table exists, without granting the right to select from it. For example, CREATE ANY INDEX or ANALYZE ANY privileges result in the insufficient privileges message for a table I don't have DML rights on. Compare the privileges granted to SCOTT with those granted to HR.

Comment: no scott has no permissions or roles - I checked dba_tab_privs and dba_role_privs. I am mystified by this

Comment: What about system privileges, such as the ones I listed? Those will not show up in either of the dba_ views you referenced, but do confer the ability to know that the obect exists but that permissions are lacking.

Comment: Look in dba_sys_privs to see if there's any privileges granted that might allow the user SCOTT to know that the table exists.